# Function to sum a column from start date until today and the same time frame before start date in python

Tags: python

The function i use do not work well, the amount of turnover before and after are not representative of the real turnover of the customer. Maybe an expert eye will understand why and can explain to me the issue there

```
def sum_func(df: pd.DataFrame, start_date: str, date_col: str, sum_col: str):
    """
    Function to sum a column from start date until today and the same time frame before start date.
    
    Arguments:
        df: Original DataFrame
        start_date: when to start summing until today
        date_col: Name of the date Column
        sum_col: Name of the Column to sum

    Returns:
        Dictionary containing the sum "after" and "before"
    """
    selected_df = df.loc[
        (df[date_col] >= pd.to_datetime(df[start_date]))
        & (df[date_col] <= pd.Timestamp.today())
    ].copy()

    selected_df_before = (
        df.loc[(df[date_col] < pd.to_datetime(df[start_date]))]
        .iloc[-selected_df.shape[0] :]
        .copy()
    )

    assert (
        selected_df_before.shape[0] == selected_df.shape[0]
    ), "Error: Not enough time before start date"

    return {
        "after": selected_df.groupby(['customer_no'])[sum_col].sum(),
        "before": selected_df_before.groupby(['customer_no'])[sum_col].sum(),
    }
```

Comment: What library is that?

Comment: @BlueRobin looks like pandas. Aon can you provide some data to run the function on?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The issue was than the before part give me null value and it shouldn't. But, I found my mistake it was due to the assert phase and the .iloc in the selected_df_before. Thank you all for taking time to add comment